# Java Spring: Web Service REST producing double backslash at JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

So i have this String e.g.

```
"B\z@b@s@rB{FpMgBrD~DK|"
```

But Spring is producing this at json:

```
"B\\z@b@s@rB{FpMgBrD~DK|"
```

And it's the same with any string that has a backslash `\`. Replacing the character before generating the json is useless, since the String is correct before the json is generated.

Every client that consumes the service could .replace("\\","\\\\") the json, but I wonder if there will be a cleaner way to solve the problema and at server side.

Here is the code for the WS:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/sinc/{ms}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public String sincronizar(@PathVariable("ms") Long ms) {
    return sincService.getSinc(ms).toString();
}
```

I have tried other ways to generate the json with libraries like Gson but the result is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the expected behavior in JSON. `\` needs to be escaped. See the specification, [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159).

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks,
> **except for the characters that must be escaped: quotation mark,
> reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F).**

Comment: So the problem must be in how it is consumed and not on how it is generated?

Comment: @MiguelAngelMerinoVega I don't know what the problem is, but the JSON is generated correctly on the server. Your client should probably use a JSON parser which will do the conversion properly for you.